# TextOverflow in Row which is inside a Column in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to develop a Card with some text widget beneath it. Look at the image below.

The problem I'm facing is when the text next to location icon is large, it overflows. I've tried with Flex, but it throws an exception. There's also a star icon at the right bottom of the card.

Here's what I want :

1. I want the text to be single line ending with .. if it's too long.
2. star should be placed at the bottom right
3. The location icon doesn't consider the left padding I gave (Padding widget)

Please help! Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here's my code :

```
Scaffold buildOffersList(OfferModel offerModel) {
      return Scaffold(
          body: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Image.network(
                    'https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/2/19250332/0fe23bee17b60d181fd43421ca3480d4_featured_v2.jpg',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    width: size.width,
                    height: size.height,
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(.6),
                    colorBlendMode: BlendMode.darken
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    child: PageHeader(pageTitle: 'Popular Offers', numberOfOffers: '20 venues', sortByText: 'Sort By: Location', filterText: 'Filter'),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                      children: List.generate(offerModel.payload.offers.length, (index) {
                        return Center(
                          child: offerCard3(offerModel.payload.offers[index]),
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
      );
    }

Widget offerCard3(Offer offer) {
      return GestureDetector(
        child: Card(
          elevation: 1.0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 18.0 / 8.0,
                child: Image.network(
                  "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/2/19250332/0fe23bee17b60d181fd43421ca3480d4_featured_v2.jpg",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(7.0, 5.0, 4.0, 5.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    getBrandName(offer),
                    getOfferTitle(offer),
                    SizedBox(height: 15.0),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[

                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                getLocationIcon(),
                                getOfferContactAddressView(offer),
                              ],
                            ),
                            getKmText(),
                          ],
                        ),

                        //Spacer(),
                        getStarIcon(),


                      ],
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

Text getOfferContactAddressView(Offer offer) {
      return Text(
        offer.offerContactAddress,
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black38,
          fontSize: 9.0,
        ),
      );
    }

    Icon getStarIcon() {
      return Icon(
        Icons.star,
        color: Colors.orange,
        size: 25,
      );
    }
```

Comment: add code of this function getOfferContactAddressView(offer).

Comment: Also, what star are you referring to?

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya Added getOfferContactAddressView(offer) functon.

Comment: @FederickJonathan, Material design icon. Added code.

Comment: @Rakesh I have edited my answer to give you the full working code unlike my first answer. Hope it will be more clear for you

Answer (score 1):

**FIrst Solution Highly Recommend**

First of all, you can use Listtile.

```
ListTile(title: Text("ListTile"),
         subtitle: Text("Sample Subtitle. \nSubtitle line 3"),
         trailing: Icon(Icons.home),
         leading: Icon(Icons.add_box),
         isThreeLine: true,
)
```

**Second Solution**

```
                   SizedBox(
                        width: 500,
                        child: new Text(
                          'Text largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee',

                          //Overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis will make you large text end with ....

                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried out second solution. it throws an exception : RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.

Comment: can you post your full code? because there is the same comment of yours in all answers so I think there is the problem in your code.

Comment: Isn't using Sizedox a bad solution?

Comment: no not at all it's better than going to a bad pattern. if you are using size with media query width then sizedbox won't give you any problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flutter package for auto resize text to contain the full text.

**auto_size_text 2.1.0** [here](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)

Answer (score 0):

It happens because the `Text Widget` doesn't know how big the width of the `Row`.

Please try this code out [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/d4788a9391a6b3603335f9f0c1a5b7e6) to help you find where you went wrong with your code. I still believe, wrapping the `Text Widget` with `Expanded` and give `overflow property` will give what you want right away.

Here's the SS of it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tried your recommendation. Threw below exception:

RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.

Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum constraints provided by the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use like below code:-

```
Expanded(
          child: Wrap(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            runAlignment: WrapAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              getOfferContactAddressView(offer),
            ],
          ),
          flex: 1,
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It throws an exception :
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.